# Back navigation / page refresh issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, reload, back

I have a blog page (part of a slider) with a blogposts list on it. I click on a post, it takes me to it, but if I try to go back (via browser's back button) to the blog list page, all i get displayed is the header and the background image.

After this, I press forward to return to the blog post (blog article) and if I press back again, it works. My page gets displayed correctly without any problems.

Does anyone know what can cause this? I forgot to mention that my intention is to make it display correctly after the back button.

I tried using the onbeforeunload event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onbeforeunload = function () {
     return "You are about to leave this order form. You will lose any information...";
    }
</script>
```

on the blogposts page but to no avail.

Does anyone know what causes this ?

Comment: You'll probably need to post a link to see a live version. Is this in all browsers? Are you using some JavaScript to load the content?

Comment: Related info: When pressing the browser's back button, whether the page is fetched from the cache or reloaded may vary from browser to browser, and may also vary based on the HTTP response headers sent by the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1);">Back</a>
```

Comment: This method gives me the following error:


An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.